# Getter for static vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static, stdvector

I have class that works. but when I add static vector and getter for it I faced compilation error.

Here is an example:

```
// Config.h file
class Config {
    static std::vector<std::string> m_RemoteVideoUrls;
    ...
public:
    static std::vector<std::string> GetRemoteVideoURLs();
};


// Config.cpp file
static std::vector<std::string> m_RemoteVideoUrls = {"some url"};
...
std::vector<std::string> Config::GetRemoteVideoURLs() {
    return m_RemoteVideoUrls;
}
```

I got this strange error during compilation in Visual Studio 2017

```
1>config.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > Config::m_RemoteVideoUrls" (?m_RemoteVideoUrls@Config@@0V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@A)
```

After few experiments I understand that something wrong with my `m_RemoteVideoUrls`.
Because this stub works:

```
std::vector<std::string> Config::GetRemoteVideoURLs() {
    return std::vector<std::string>{"a", "b"};// m_RemoteVideoUrls;
}
```

but this don't work:

```
std::vector<std::string> Config::GetRemoteVideoURLs() {
    LoadConfigIfRequired();
    std::vector<std::string> tmp = m_RemoteVideoUrls;
    return std::vector<std::string>{"a", "b"};// m_RemoteVideoUrls;
}
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
static std::vector<std::string> m_RemoteVideoUrls = {"some url"};
```

is just an unrelated global variable, to give a definition to a static member it should be

```
std::vector<std::string> Config::m_RemoteVideoUrls = {"some url"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared a global vector with same name as the static one, but the static one itself was never defined. It is necessary to specify where the vector belongs to (specify the scope):

```
static std::vector<std::string> Config::m_RemoteVideoUrls = {"some url"};
//                              ^^^^^^^^
```

Actually, you even could have both vectors at the same time:

```
static std::vector<std::string> m_RemoteVideoUrls = {"some url"};
static std::vector<std::string> Config::m_RemoteVideoUrls = {"another url"};
```

Which one is used when? Well, depends on the scope you are at: member functions of class Config use the static member, members of other classes and global functions use the global one (unless you specify scope explicitly: `::m_RVU` vs. `Config::m_RVU`).

Of course, not a good idea to have identical names, it's just for illustration...

Then there's a second issue:

Do you really intend to return the static member by value (i. e. make a copy all the time)?

You might prefer returning a reference:

```
public:
    static std::vector<std::string> const& getRemoteVideoURLs();
    //                              ^^^^^^
```